# how to override grid variable in bootstrap 4 angular

Tags: angular, variables, sass, bootstrap-4

how to really override bootstrap variables?
I try this one and not working

```
// overrides.scss
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';

@import 'variables.scss'; // my own variables
$grid-columns: 12;
$grid-gutter-width: 16px;
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

// global styles
@import 'overrides.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

I'm using Angular 2+ and just want to set the gutter width of row from 30px to 16px, any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to import Bootstrap twice. Just import it once at the end...

```
@import 'bootstrap/functions';
@import 'bootstrap/variables';

$grid-columns: 12;
$grid-gutter-width: 16px;

@import 'bootstrap';
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/wSyODZFc0b